# Getting an AttributeError even when not using it as an attribute?

Tags: python, class, object, attributes, attributeerror

I created a class/object `Scoreboard()` and also a function `show_score()`. I'm importing this object in another python file to call and use some of its functions.

```
import pygame.font

class Scoreboard():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, stats):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.stats = stats

        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

        self.prep_score

    def prep_score(self):
        score_str = str(self.stats.score)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(
                           score_str, True, 
                           self.text_color, 
                           self.ai_settings.bg_color)

        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20

    def show_score(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
```

When I run the other file, where I've written `sb = Scoreboard()`, I get an error in

```
line 28, in show_score
self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)

AttributeError: 'Scoreboard' object has no attribute 'score_image'
```

which sounds bizarre to me because `score_image` is not an attribute (or at least I don't think it is). 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `self.score_image` uses `score_image` as an attribute of `Scoreboard`. The fact that it is not an attribute (as you wrote) is exactly what Python is complaining about.

Comment: So how do I fix this? Get rid of it altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not call `prep_score`; `score_image` is never *created* - change

```
class Scoreboard():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, stats):
        ....
        ....
        self.prep_score
```

to

```
class Scoreboard():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, stats):
        ....
        ....
        self.prep_score()
```

Comment: That simple change fixed it! THANK YOUUU